# mysqli insert into database

Tags: php, mysqli

Hello all i have this script and i will not insert into the database and i get no errors :S, do you know what it is?

```
    function createUser($username, $password) {
    $mysql = connect();
    if($stmt = $mysql->prepare('INSERT INTO users (username, password, alder, hood, fornavn, efternavn, city, ip, level, email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'))  {
      $stmt->bind_param('ssssssssss',$username,$password, $alder, $hood, $fornavn, $efternavn, $city, $ip, $level, $email);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->close();
    } else {
      echo 'error: ' . $mysql->error;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you get an error from the `$stmt->execute();` call? Check `$stmt->error` (which is a string) just before you run `$stmt->close();`

Maybe some of your values should not be strings, such as the `level` and/or `hood` parameters? They look like typical integer parameters.